# Regular expression for y,yes, Y, YES ,1

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex for validating a string. The regular expression should pass the string if it contains any of the following: `y`, `Y`, `yes`, `YES`, `1`. The letters  can be in any case. I am new to regular expression and JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looks simple

Comment: 'hello y here is yes i am Y you are Yes'.match(/yes|y|1/gi)
remove g if you know that only one of them exists

Comment: *contains any of the following*: do you mean "contains", or do you mean "exactly equal to"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add an optional group as well as a case-insensitive `i` modifier.

```
/y(?:es)?|1/i.test(str)
```

or

```
/[1y](?:es)?/i.test(str)
```

or

```
/[y1]/i.test(str)
```

For doing exact match.

```
/^(?:y(?:es)?|1)$/i.test(str)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the initial `(?:`? Or the second one for that matter? What's wrong with `/^y(es)?|1$/i`?

Comment: @torazaburo no, regex would treat `^y(es)?` and `1$` as two seperate terms so this would match any string which ends with 1 or any string which starts with y.

Comment: Then `/^(y(es)?|1)$/i`?

Comment: ya, I used `(?:` non-capturing group instead of capturing group because capturing group will decrease the performance as compared to non-capturing groups.